# How do i create a 3d rotating image in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, 3d

What i need to do: I need to load a 3D model of an image into the viewcontroller. The image must rotate according to the users touch. Also if the user selects a part of the image, a function for that part must open.

I am assuming that i will have to load a 3d graphics kit. I have started looking into openGLES and Nineveh GL.

This is for a native app and not a game using sprite kit. How do i go about implementing this into my app? Could somebody also tell me what documentation i need to refer to?

Comment: Check out the documentation for `SceneKit`...

Comment: @Grimxn I checked it out but it doesnt seem to be what i need per se.. Correct me if I'm wrong but i think scene kit can only be used if you are making a game. Is there anything that i can use that i can actually add to a single view app?

Comment: That's not the case at all - it's just a subclass of UIView - you can stick one in anywhere.

Comment: @Grimxn Thanks for the clarification brother, I will look into it. Also, if you know of any other options, I would love to hear them.

P.s. do you have any idea how i can select portions of the image to do different tasks?

Comment: @Grimxn I have gotten comfortable with using SceneKit and its working pretty well for me, so thanks again.. Do you know how i could cause selection of different portions of the same image to perform a different function? Is there some way i could divide up the screen according to the image?